# how to avoid repetition of <select></select>?

Tags: html

Say, I have 50 input fields and in each field there is a dropdown list having options 1, 2, 3, .., 100.

Simply it can be done by inserting the long list of options in every input fields by  commands.

Is there anyway by which we can write the full list only for one input field and refer it in the other input fields

Comment: With Javascript, yes. HTML alone, no.

Comment: Im finding it difficult to visualise your issue. Can you provide some code so we can see what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this question correctly this sounds like it would be a great case for using some server side logic like php or asp. A simple FOR loop would make it easy to maintain without adding the complexity / reliance on JavaScript that a client - side function brings into play.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to append the options list to all dropdown lists with a certain class name in the `$().ready()` event handler.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/z5pM5/15/)